# Reach a method inside usercontrol c# from mainpage c#

Tags: c#, uwp

In my uwp project i have a `User Control` that i have a template of a room in, but in my `Mainpage.cs` i get all the values i get from a `API`.

In the template i have multiple `x:names` that i can't reach inside the `Mainpage.cs` file. Beacuse of that i have made a function in my `UserControl.cs`.

This is a sample code in `UserControl.cs` of a method that i want to reference in `Mainpage.cs`:

```
public void OnBooked()
{
    //do stuff...
}
```

The class in `UserControl.cs` is named `TemplateGrid`.

I tried to do something like this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
TemplateGrid.OnBooked();
```

My question is how do I reference the method `OnBooked()` in `Mainpage.cs`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you instanciated the TemplateGrid in your Mainpage.cs?

Comment: @k1dev I mean I have the `Using` of the namespace That the TemplateGrid is located in.

Comment: Add some more code please

Comment: @k1dev What code do you want?

Comment: Besides of the using, somewhere in your Mainpage.cs, inside a `method`, you will need to instantiate your `TemplateGrid`. For example, in your `Form_Load` method : `var templateGrid = new TemplateGrid();`, and then you should be able to access its methods like this: `templateGrid.OnBooked();`

Comment: Okey, I will test that as soon as possible, I'am going for lunch right now :) Thanks for helping! @k1dev

Comment: @k1dev It worked perfectly! thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @k1dev The values of the method `OnBooked()`  is cleared when I use `var templategrid = new TemplateGrid();`.  Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: what do you mean